# Is it possible to change Common Lisp's `getf` function default value to something else than NIL?

Tags: common-lisp, default

The function `getf` works like that:

```
CL-USER> (getf '(:name "pedro") :name)
"pedro"
CL-USER> (getf '(:name "pedro") :whatever)
NIL
```

`NIL` is the default value. Is it possible to change it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. The documentation [defines](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_getf.htm) this possibility:

```
(getf place indicator &optional default)
```

Thus, the *default* value it's actually an optional argument. An example using it would be:

```lisp
CL-USER> (getf '(:name "pedro") :name "no-answer")
"pedro"
CL-USER> (getf '(:name "pedro") :whatever "no-answer")
"no-answer"
```